# Implement Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have been told to implement the [*Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) in R studio, considering lambda's initial value equals 10. The algorithm must stop when the gradient's norm is lower than the tolerance. I also need to print the values that x1, x2, λ, ∇f(x), d1 and d2 take for each iteration. Any ideas on how to do it? Many thanks in advance

This is what I have:

```
library(pracma)
library(matlib)
MetodeLM<-function(f,xi,t)
{
  l=10
  stop=FALSE
  x<-xi
  k=0
  while (stop==FALSE){
    dk<- inv(hessian(f,x)+l*diag(diag(hessian(f,x))))
    x1<-x+dk
    if (Norm(grad(f,x1))<t){
      stop<-TRUE
    }
    else{
      if (f(x1) < f(x)){
        l<-l/10
        k<-k+1
        stop<-FALSE
      }
      else{
        l<-l*10
        stop<-FALSE
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Not everyone knows what the Levenberg Marquadt algorithm is, so by not defining it, you limit the number of people who can help you.  Further, by not demonstrating any effort on your own part (what did you try?  why didn't it work?  did you get any error messages?) you do not motivate people to help you.

Comment: I've just added what I have, sorry

Answer (score 4):

Correcting a few mistakes in your code, the following implementation of Levenberg Marquadt's algorithm should work (note that the update rule for the algorithm is shown in the following figure):

[image]

```
library(pracma)

# tolerance = t, λ = l 
LM <- function(f, x0, t, l=10, r=10) { 
    
    x <- x0
    k <- 0
    while (TRUE) {
      H <- hessian(f, x)
      G <- grad(f, x)
      dk <- inv(H + l * diag(nrow(H))) %*% G   # dk <- solve(H + l * diag(nrow(H)), G)
      x1 <- x - dk   # update rule
      print(k)  # iteration
      # print(l) # λ
      print(x1) # x1, x2
      print(G)  # ∇f(x)
      print(dk) # d1, d2
      if (Norm(G) < t) break
      l <- ifelse(f(x1) < f(x), l / r, l * r)
      k <- k + 1
      x <- x1 # update the old point 
    }
}
```

For example, with the following function, the non-linear optimization algorithm will quickly find a local minimum point (in the 10th iteration) as shown below

```
f <- function(x) {
   return ((x[1]^2+x[2]-25)^2 + (x[1]+x[2]^2-25)^2)
}

x0 <- rep(0,2)
LM(f, x0, t=1e-3, l=400, r=2)
# [1] 0
#      [,1]
# [1,] 0.165563
# [2,] 0.165563
# [1] -50 -50
#      [,1]
# [1,] -0.165563
# [2,] -0.165563
# [1] 1
#      [,1]
# [1,] 0.7986661
# [2,] 0.7986661
# [1] -66.04255 -66.04255
#      [,1]
# [1,] -0.6331031
# [2,] -0.6331031
# ...
# [1] 10
#     [,1]
# [1,] 4.524938
# [2,] 4.524938
# [1] 0.0001194898 0.0001194898
#         [,1]
# [1,] 5.869924e-07
# [2,] 5.869924e-07
```

The following animation shows the convergence to the local minimum point for the function:

[image]

The following one is with LoG function

[image]

Comment: You most likely want to replace `inv(H + l * diag(nrow(H))) %*% G` with `solve(H + l * diag(nrow(H)), G)`. For numerical reason, you almost never wants to invert and multiply rather than solving.

Comment: Yeah, just did not want to change OP's code, since he is using the function from `pracma`

Comment: I see. Nice answer.

Comment: I am not the OP. I have given it a +1.